# Xcode External Build System Project Can't Find wchar.h

Tags: c++, xcode, makefile

I'm trying to figure out how to use Xcode's "External Build System" project template to do some `C++` coding. I've set it up with a very simple test project, just to make sure that I understand the configuration. I'm using `make` to build the project. When I try to run it, the build fails with the error message `'wchar.h' file not found.`

Here are the steps I took to set up the project:

1. Create a new Project, using the `Other -> External Build System` template.
2. Set the `Build Tool` option to `/usr/bin/make`.
3. Copy my source file, `ex_3_4.cpp` to the directory where the Xcode project is located, and add it to the project using the `Add files to "TestProject"...` menu option.
4. Copy the `makefile` to the directory where the Xcode project is located.

Everything works if I run `make` from the terminal - I get an executable that runs fine, and there is no trouble finding `wchar.h` or any other headers. So I know that this is a problem with something in the project settings.

Here is the code in the source file:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

And here is my `makefile`:

```
all:
    clang++ ex_3_4.cpp -o ex_3_4

clean:
    rm ex_3_4
```

I can't find any place in the project settings where I can specify a search path for the `wchar.h` file (or any other header files for that matter), so I'm not sure how to fix this. I feel like it must be something simple.

If it makes any difference, I've been using Xcode 7.3, but I've also tried it with the new Xcode 8.0. I get the same error message using either version.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to add a library target to your project, add it as a dependency on your project and then, your .h into the Headers section

[image]